# What does data_provider stands for? [BloC Design Pattern]

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am following some videos/courses for BloC. A structure like this took my attention:

[image]

And I applied the folder structure. What I couldn't figure out is what should be inside in data_provider how it should look? What am i supposed to put in it?

Answer (score 0):

Bloc and Cubits are used in state management of your flutter.For this case the data_providers directory will contain the functionality of fetching the data to be availed throughout your app probably from an API or whatever the source of your data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).